# Ionic 5 w/ Capacitor 'plugin_not_installed'

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

Ionic 5 with Capacitor getting 'plugin_not_installed' with plugin 'cordova.plugins.diagnostic'. Tried installing with [this doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic).

I have:

- `config.xml` has
  `<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^5.30.0" />`.
- `package.json` has

```
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      ...
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {}
      ...
    }
 }
```

and

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.30.0",
    ...
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^6.0.2",
    ...
}
```

Here's my output for `cordova plugin list`

```
com.googlemaps.ios 3.9.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.7.1 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.4.1 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 6.0.2 "Diagnostic"
```

And have tried these commands:

```
ionic capacitor sync ios
cordova build
ionic build
ionic cordova run ios -l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when using Cordova plugin inside a capacitor project, use this commands.

```
npm install cordova.plugins.diagnostic @ionic-native/diagnostic
```

Refer [docs for details](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/using-cordova-plugins)

Secondly, remove your `platform` and `ios` folders that have been already created.
Then, for Capacitor follow these commands.

```
ionic capacitor add ios
ionic build
ionic capacitor sync ios
ionic capacitor open ios
```

For any subsequent changes to your code, you just have to run

`ionic build && ionic capacitor sync ios` (if you have added any new package/plugin)

`ionic build && ionic capacitor copy ios` (if only code has been changed)

You say your project is built on capacitor, then you don't have to run `ionic cordova run ios` command, or any `cordova` commands

Refer this [command docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-sync)

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed response. Unfortunately, I started getting this error: `mainviewcontroller.h' file not found`.

And came across this post: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-5-capacitor-cordovagooglemaps-mainviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-build-error/196672/4

It seems that the GoogleMaps plugin has problems with Capacitor.

Comment: So I guess I have to switch to a pure Cordova setup?

Comment: Not at all.. dont use the cordova plugin.. google maps can successfully be integrated in a capacitor app too.. but you will have to use the web SDK and not the native SDK which the cordova plugin uses.. read this article https://www.joshmorony.com/google-maps-in-ionic-2-native-or-web/  also, follow this tutorial https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-google-maps-geolocation-geocoder-application/#.X8OitVMzbMI

Comment: So, I actually followed those two same articles to get to where I am now. I'm not sure if I followed them incorrectly, but I actually found this Web SDK implementation from Angular themselves, as part of Material. Since i'm using an Angular project, it seemed to make sense to use that. https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps